# Why is it allowed to add bgColor to <head> and <table> tag as attribute

Tags: html, css

*I know many of you will suggest to use css, but this is the question usually we triggered during interviews.*

I was searching how to add background color to html tag element without using any external css or inline css.
Then I came to know that we can add bgColor to directly, like

```
<head bgColor="#000000"> or <table bgColor="#000000">
```

with with div it doesn't work.

```
<div bgColor="#000000">
```

(above div bgColor will not work)

please help me to understand why is it so ?

Comment: Well that's deprecated. You shouldn't even be doing that. You might have to type a little more in your `style` tag or your css file, or even inline styles. But never `bgColor`. And I honestly don't know 100% why it doesn't work for a `div` but for the other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the `bgColor` attribute is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore. To answer your question, this attribute was specifically intended for styling the background color of table or body elements. Use CSS to style the background of your divs (ex: `background-color: black;`)

Comment: Thanks @MadGab, for the info, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In html5 that attribute is obsolete

Standards:

- HTML5

Check this link, there is a part:
"The following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language), and must not be used by authors"

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html

Now check this link:

- HTML 4

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor

It says:

"This attribute sets the background color of the canvas for the document body (the BODY element) or for tables (the TABLE, TR, TH, and TD elements)"